# Please help me understand the last part of this proof of Cauchy's Integral Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

[This](https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Analysis/Complex_Variables_with_Applications_(Orloff)/05%3A_Cauchy_Integral_Formula/5.03%3A_Proof_of_Cauchy%27s_integral_formula) has a proof of Cauchy's Integral Theorem, I have a question regarding the last part, Equation $5.3.8$ to be precise. How did the line integral of $\frac{1}{z-z_0}$ along $C$ come out to be $2\pi i$? I know this would have worked out if $z_0$ was the centre of $C$, in which case we could parameterise any point on the curve in terms of $z_0$ and some $t, 0\le t\le2\pi$ as $z=z_0 + re^{it}$, after which one could integrate easily by substitution.
But clearly, in this theorem, $z_0$ has been chosen to be *any* point inside the region. Can you please explain how the integral would still come out to be $2\pi i$?

Comment: I had much the same issues when I first encountered these proofs. What these proofs implicitly assume you know is the concept of “homotopy invariance”. Point is, the integral of a simple curve around any $z_0$ is in fact *identical* to the integral of a circle centred at $z_0$, since each contour can be smoothly deformed into the other. There are more details, but that’s the overview

Comment: If your function is analytic everywhere but at $z_0$ then any integral around a closed contour that does not encircle $z_0$ equals 0.  This allows you to deform the path until you have it in the shape of something you know how to integrate.

Comment: @DougM Yes, I studied that a while ago. How exactly does that come into use here, because $z_0$ here *is* part of the region enclosed by C?

Comment: @AmbicaGovind Maybe draw the circle of radius $r$ around $z_0$, along with $C$, and see if you can use what Doug suggested? Just an idea.

Comment: Cauchy's Theorem (4.7 of that same text) lets you deform a loop into a small circle around $z_0$.

Comment: Please, use descriptive titles. "Please help me understand the last part of this proof" says nothing about the subject of the question.

Comment: @jjagmath Thanks, I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Integrals around closed contours around a region that is analytic are always 0.

Traveling opposite directions along the same segment the integral has opposite signs.

[image]

If the function is analytic everywhere but $a$, we can add closed contours that do not include $a$ without changing the value of the integral.  Adding the right contours together we can trim the shape of the contour to just about any shape we want.

[image]

Suppose $f(z)$ is analytic everywhere. $\frac {f(z)}{z-a}$ is analytic everywhere but $a.$

Let $\gamma$ be a contour with $a$ inside the contour.

$\oint_\gamma \frac {f(z)}{z-a} \ dz = \oint_{|z-a| = 1} \frac {f(z)}{z-a} \ dz = \oint_{|z-a| = \delta} \frac {f(z)}{z-a} \ dz$

We can make $\delta$ sufficiently small such that $f(z)-f(a)$ is very small.

$\oint_{|z-a| = \delta} \frac {f(z)}{z-a} \ dz = f(a) \oint_{|z-a| = \delta} \frac {1}{z-a} \ dz = 2\pi i f(a)$